# Trigger is not working, updating the Standard Account Rating field?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a formula field in Account object that is calculating value using formula Today()-LastActivityDate(), and return type of formula is a number.
So based on that number I am trying to set the Rating field to one the picklist value using trigger.

```
trigger CalActivityTrigger on Account ( after update) {
    for(Account a:Trigger.new){
        if(a.CalActivity__c==0)
        {
           a.Rating='Hot';
        }
        update a;
    }
}
```

What other option we have for the same scenario?

Comment: Have you tried to debug into the trigger and see which part is not working?

Comment: Yes error is: CalActivityTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.CalActivityTrigger: line 6, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues in your code:

1. You can't update records in trigger.new in an update trigger. Refer here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm
2. All triggers and bulk triggers in Salesforce. Which means you can't put DML (update) in a loop.

To fix your code:

```
trigger CalActivityTrigger on Account ( after update) {
    if(Util.inAccountTrigger) {
        return;
    }
    TriggerUtil.inAccountTrigger = true; //This is to avoid infinite loop

    List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Account a:Trigger.new){
        if(a.CalActivity__c==0)
        {
           Account newAcc = new Account();
           newAcc.Id = a.Id;
           newAcc.Rating='Hot';

           accToUpdate.add(newAcc);
        }
    }

    update accToUpdate;
}
```

And you need to define a static variable to avoid infinite loop.

```
class TriggerUtil
{
    Boolean inAccountTrigger = false;
}
```

Comment: If (a.CalActivity__c==0) then Rating field should be set to warm, which is not setting.

Comment: In your code, it should be set into Hot, not warm. If it is not still not set, debug into the code and let me know which step is wrong.

Comment: Can we also do the same using workflow and process builder?

Comment: @avidForce I think they are both achievable. I am kind of code person so I would prefer using trigger. But I don't see a reason you can't use workflow or process builder here.